# How to debug gulp-inject error: "gulp-inject Nothing to inject into index.html"?

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

In my gulp task I get the following error during a gulp-inject:

> gulp-inject Nothing to inject into index.html

And nothing is injected into my index.html indeed.

I think, I have a source to be injected present as well as injection placeholders in my index.html correctly specified and in place.

What does this error message mean?
Can I get more information on this error?